# DropzoneJS - create two instances on the same page

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

Currently I have instantiated my only dropzone like this:

```
$(function () { // Dropzone
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div#dropzone1', {
        url: '/wiki/uploadpdf', 
        acceptedFiles: 'application/pdf'});

        document.querySelector('div#dropzone1').classList.add('dropzone');

        myDropzone.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {         
            formData.append('subject', 'subject1');
            formData.append('text', 'some text');
        }
    });
});
```

I do it this way because I want to use the 'sending' option to send additional data to the PHP file.

This works fine, but when I want to instantiate another dropzone, it does not display anything. For  the second one I also want to send additional data, so I probably have to find a solution that does the same things as the first one.

Simply creating another Dropzone object

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div#dropzone2', { // etc }
```

within another

```
$(function () { }
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery already, I find easier to use the dropzone plugin for jQuery, here an example of how to have two dropzones in a page with different cofiguration.

html:

```
<form id="dropzone1" class="dropzone"></form>
<form id="dropzone2" class="dropzone"></form>
```

script:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$('#dropzone1').dropzone({
  url: '/wiki/uploadpdf', 
  acceptedFiles: 'application/pdf',
  init: function(){
    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
        formData.append('subject', 'subject1');
        formData.append('text', 'some text');
    })
  }
});

$('#dropzone2').dropzone({
  // Here goes the configuration
  // same as on the first one but you can
  // use different values if you need to
  url: '/wiki/uploadpdf', 
  acceptedFiles: 'application/pdf',
  init: function(){
    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
        formData.append('subject', 'subject1');
        formData.append('text', 'some text');
    })
  }
});
```

Here an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UxaV9GS0ufOtDzoFhBLG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @wallek876, why didn't I try this? :-)